# How to set printing document name in java

Tags: java, printing

I am printing 4 copies of a document. Each copy has only a single line change.
While saving it through "microsoft print to PDF", I am getting dialogue box to set location path and  has default name of document as "java printing". 
How can I programmatically change name of the document?

I have read about the `DocumentName` attribute class, but I don't know how to use it with a `printerJob` object.

Please help with an example.

Comment: Could you share the piece of code you already have, so others could help you out from there?

Answer (score 3):

Please try this:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setJobName("examplefilename");
```